# d3.js matching nodes to links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I made a graph of rectangles and I fixed the Y-Axis of the nodes so I can just move it on the X-Axis alone. But since I've done this the links or the lines went every where and I don't know how to get this fixed. 
([My graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vshb.png) ).

Here is my code :

```
function arbre(graph) { // graph is my Json file
        var width = 1000,
            height = 1000,
            wrect=300,
            hrect=400;
        var color = d3.scale.category20();
        var nodes=graph.nodes;
        var root = nodes[0];
        var stx=sty=50; 

        root.fixed = true;
        root.x = 400;
        root.y = 30; 

        //on ajoute les paramètre x2 et y2 au noeud
        for(var key in nodes)
        {
            nodes[key].x2=wrect;
            nodes[key].y2=hrect;
        }

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            //.charge(-200) // -120 200
            //.alpha(0);
            .linkDistance(50) // 20 200
            .gravity(0.5)
            .charge(function(d, i) { return i ? 0 : -2000; })
            .size([width, height]);

         // définition des noeuds et des liens de la force
         force.nodes(nodes)
              .links(graph.links)
              .start();

        var svg = d3.select("#graph") 
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);


          // création des liens sous forme de lignes
          var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
              .data(graph.links)
              .enter()
              .append("g")                  // groupe pour les links 
              .attr("class","link-group")  
              .append("line")
              .attr("class", "link")
              .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d); });

            // création des nodes sous forme de rectangles
          var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter()
              .append("g")
              .attr("class","node-group")
              .append("rect")  
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("width", wrect) 
              .attr("height", hrect)  
              .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.id_projet); })

              .attr("y", function(d) {if(d.type == 'convention') d.y = 300;})//return 300; })
              .call(force.drag);

            // Ajouter des infos au rectangles 
            var id = svg.selectAll(".node-group")
                    .data(graph.nodes) 
                    .append("text")
                    .text(function(d) {if(d.type == 'projet')return d.data.id_projet; })
                    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                    .attr("font-size", "10px");


            var acronyme = svg.selectAll(".node-group")
                    .data(graph.nodes) 
                    .append("text")
                    .text(function(d) {return d.data.acronyme_projet; })
                    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                    .attr("font-size", "10px");

          // la fonction tick
          force.on("tick", function(e){
              var q = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes),
              i = -1,
              n = nodes.length;

            console.log(nodes);
              // traitement de la collision des rectangles  
              while (++i < n)
              {
                q.visit(collide(nodes[i])); 
              }

            // mise à jour des positions des rectangles et des lignes     
            node.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
              //.attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
              .attr("y", function(d) { 
                if(d.type == "projet") return d.y;
                if(d.type == "convention") return 300; 
                if(d.type == "budget") return 600;
              });
            console.log(nodes);
            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x+stx; })  // d: data() of links
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y+stx; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x+stx; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y+stx; });

            // positionnement du text dans les rectangles    
            id.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x+2; }) // d: data() of texte
              .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y+10; });

            acronyme.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x+2; }) // d: data() of texte
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y+20; });                        
          });

          // to avoid overlapping 
          function overlap(a, b){

             if(((a.x < b.x && b.x < a.x2) && (a.y < b.y && b.y < a.y2)) || ((a.x < b.x2 && b.x2 < a.x2) && (a.y < b.y2 && b.y2 < a.y2)))
             {
                return true;
             }
         }

    //-------------my collision function
        function collide(node) {

                node.x2=node.x+wrect;
                node.y2=node.y+hrect;

          var nx1, nx2, ny1, ny2, padding;
          padding = 20;
          nx1 = node.x - padding;
          nx2 = node.x2 + padding;
          ny1 = node.y - padding;
          ny2 = node.y2 + padding;
        console.log(node.x,node.x2,node.y,node.y2);
        console.log(nx1, nx2, ny1, ny2, padding);

          return function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
          console.log(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2);
          var dx, dy;
          if (quad.point && (quad.point !== node)) {
          if (overlap(node, quad.point)) {

            console.log(node.x2,quad.point.x, quad.point.x2, node.x);
            console.log(node.x2-quad.point.x, quad.point.x2 - node.x);
            dx = Math.min(node.x2 - quad.point.x, quad.point.x2 - node.x) / 2;
            node.x -= dx;
            quad.point.x += dx;
            dy = Math.min(node.y2 - quad.point.y, quad.point.y2 - node.y) / 2;
            node.y -= dy;
            quad.point.y += dy;
          }
        }
        return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
      };
    };
}
```

Comment: The code would be really helpful...

Comment: Your issue can't really be analysed without the associated source code. Could you add it to the question please?

Answer (score 1):

Without the code, I can just say you didn't update the drawing *after* changing the y-coordinate of your boxes. Check the order of your instructions, and you should be able to fix this.

To make it more explicit, you probably have the following sequence of instructions:

- draw the edges
- change *y* coordinate
- draw the nodes

You need to pull the 2nd up, that is:

- change *y* coordinate
- draw the edges
- draw the nodes

Comment: I don't understand people who downvote these kind of answers without leaving a comment.. here have my upvote.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12420938)

Comment: @Robert Well it is clear enough from the screenshot that the solution is to switch the instructions changing the coordinate with the one doing the drawing of the edges. This is an answer in itself, as detailed as anyone can provide without seeing more of the code. I'll make it more detailed if/when the OP gives more information.